# Check if a word exists in a dictionary doesn't find any word

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to find the dictionary contain that word or not.
Word comes from the list is incrementing by a loop.
Please give a suggestion if you're not getting question comment below.

```
n = int(input())

d = {}

for i in range(n):
   text = input().split()     
   d[text[0]] = text[1]

list = []

for i in range(n):
    list.append(input())

for i in range(n):
    ***`if list[i] in d == True:`***
        print(d[i])

    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

Comment: just `if list[i] in d`. What is your exact problem?

Comment: `if list[i] in d: print(d[list[i]])`

Comment: "_Please give a suggestion if you're not getting question comment below._"  \*Comments\*

Comment: @MunafHajir What is your exact problem?

Comment: `"a" in list[i] == True` chains operators `in` and `==` short-circuit fashion. Since `list[i]` is different from `True`, global condition is always False.

Comment: example: in dictionary the word contain sam and i am taking input in list example that is also contain sam i want to check that input of list[i] is contain in the dictionary or not ex: in list[i] = sam and in dictionary contains the sam it have to print that dictionary with key value.

Comment: @MunafHajir all those benevolent comments would like you to [edit] your question and tell us exactly _what is your exact problem_ (although we already figured it out, the question is unclear). For example: "it always prints "Not found", why is that?" (you can reuse that :)). Ok I edited the title myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pinpointed the problem:

```
if list[i] in d == True:
```

`list[i] in d == True` chains operators `in` and `==` in short-circuit fashion (like `(list[i] in d) and (d==True)`)

Since `d` is different from `True`, global condition is always `False` and it seems that the word is not in the dictionary whereas it is.

Either protect with parentheses (works, but ugly):

```
if (list[i] in d) == True:
```

or use pythonic truth test (never compare to `True` or `False` anyway, use `in d` or `not in d`):

```
if list[i] in d:
```

BTW as COLDSPEED noted, now that the statement works, you'll have an error here because `d` has no integer keys:

```
print(d[i])   # d[list[i]] would be correct (but ugly)
```

So rewrite your loop getting rid of the indexes while you're at it,directly iterating on the elements (and getting rid of `list` as a variable as this is the `list` type, switched to `l`):

```
for item in l:
    if item in d:
        print(item)
```

nicer right?

Comment: I've never understood the propensity many have to use logical operators to make Boolean values out of already Boolean expressions.

Comment: @FredLarson yeah. You don't need it even in K&R C... I know.

Comment: This solves half the problem. There's still the issue of OP using integers to index a dict...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, that's the next problem. With statement always `False` that couldn't be reached. Editing. Thx